# How to get rid of unwanted "datamoshing" effect in a UDP video stream using VLC and GStreamer?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, vlc

So, I have a setup of a laptop running Windows and a Jetson Xavier NX, and I'm trying to stream the webcam from the laptop to Jetson. I have connected these devices to the same network and started a Stream from the laptop using VLC Media Player. I chose the following options:

[image: Screenshot of the VLC Stream]
[image: Screenshot of the Stream destination]
[image: Screenshot of the Transcoding]

Next, I opened a terminal window in Jetson and launched the following GStreamer pipeline to receive the stream:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=1234 ! queue max-size-buffers=0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I am able to obtain the video stream just fine, however, there is a ["datamoshing"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEerMwhVAaQ) effect to the stream, which I don't really like, and would like to get rid of, since I will be using this video stream for object recognition. I have researched the ways of getting rid of this issue by reducing the caching to 0ms, changing up the codecs, etc, but nothing has proved successful yet. I've tried my best to look for a similar issue, but even then I wasn't able to find a solution, perhaps because I don't really know the legal name of this "datamoshing" effect. Anyone know how to solve this issue? Perhaps udp is not the best way?

Comment: Might be caused by a missing **keyframe** (which _should_ be transmitted first if working okay). Try listening to the port before VLC sends the stream out. This way you don't miss any packets.